# TypeScript Mapped Types - How to get type of nested objects

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 2.1 has a great feature of [Mapped Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types) that can type keys of objects and get type by the key. For example you can change the structure of original object:

```
type FactoryUnit<T> = {
    self: T;
};

type Factory<T> = {
    compile: () => {[P  in keyof T]: FactoryUnit<T[P]>};
    clone: (mutator: (origin: T) => T) => Factory<T>;
};

function buildFactory<T>(v: T): Factory<T> {
    return null;
}

const imp = buildFactory({ one: 1, two: 2 }).compile();
console.log(imp.one.self);
```

But what if I want to change objects inside. For example I am sure that the object values have `modifiers` property and I can use some function to use it.

```
type FactoryUnit<T, M> = {
    self: T;
    modifiers: <R>(f: (v: M) => R) => R;
};

type Factory<T extends { [key: string]: { modifiers: M } }, M> = {
    compile: () => {[P  in keyof T]: FactoryUnit<T[P], T[P]['modifiers']>};
    clone: (mutator: (origin: T) => T) => Factory<T, M>;
};

function buildFactory<T extends { [key: string]: { modifiers: M } }, M>(v: T): Factory<T, M> {
    return null;
}

const imp = buildFactory({
    one: { one: 1, modifiers: { mOne: 11 } },
    two: { two: 2, modifiers: { mTwo: 11 } }
}).compile();

console.log(imp.one.modifiers(v => v.mOne)); // v is any
```

I tried to tell TypeScript about `modifiers` key but how to type value to make ts to infer it? How to tell TypeScript that `modifiers` property has `M` type?

Comment: 1. I don't think this will work with TypeScript 2.1 due to issues with eagerly evaluating the type parameter (try the nightlies).

2. Did you mean to make `modifiers` have the type `<R>(f: (v: M) => R) => R`?

Comment: 1. I think this aprroach is incorrect in this line `<T extends { [key: string]: { modifiers: M } }, M>` as M is at the same time is single generic and type of each (many) values in object
2. yes, I meant this, corrected it in the post